# Rewriting for a dynamic subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I've set up a dynamic subdomain in Apache 2.4.18 like so;

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/*">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAlias *.example
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%-2+
    LogLevel rewrite:trace5

    ErrorLog /tmp/errors.log
    Alias /404.php /var/www/404.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</VirtualHost>
```

And in every folder in `/var/www/vhosts` I create the following `.htaccess` to rewrite all requests to `index.php` inside the folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Require all granted
```

How would I go about merging the `.htaccess` into my Apache site configuration? I tried just copying the contents of my `.htaccess` into the `<Directory />` section at the top of my Apache site configuration but ended up with a recursion error.

An example how things should be routed;

```
my.domain.example -> /var/www/vhosts/my.domain/index.php
my.domain.example/hello -> /var/www/vhosts/my.domain/index.php/hello
test.example -> /var/www/vhosts/test/index.php
test.example/world -> /var/www/vhosts/test/index.php/world
```

Comment: The `RewriteRule` operates on _absolute_ paths in the real host configuration (so including a leading slash), but on _relative_ paths in dynamic configuration files. The reason is obvious, once you think about it...

Comment: So do I need to set a `RewriteBase`?

Comment: If you want a unified rule then what is purpose of having `VirtualDocumentRoot` ?

Comment: A ``RewriteBase`` is only defined for dynamic configuration files. The reason is, once again, obvious, once you think about it...